# Visual Studio 2017 references to code in other projects not resolved when i open the solution

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2017 where projects reference other projects in the solution; when I open the solution and I open a project the references to code defined in other projects seems not resolved (is like the other projects had not yet been loaded) I must click every single projects, expand it and then the reference are all resolved. Is there a work around to avoid this?

**UPDATE**: I  have Lightweight Solution enabled for the single solution 
and Resharper installed.

To be clear **the solution builds** but visual studio show me **in red references to code in other projects** and i get **errors in the error windows** even if the building succeed

**UPDATE 2** As suggested by Pankaj Kapare if I disable the Lightweight modality for the solution the problem disappear but still persist if I enable Lightweight again

[image]

[image]

Comment: What happens when you clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Builds with no errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have turned "Lightweight Solution load" option on. You can disable it using following steps:

1. Go to Tools > Option > Projects and Solutions > General settings page.
2. Uncheck "Lighweight solution load for all solutions" if its checked.
3. Reopen Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes that fix the problem.... but I'm wondering why  I get that behavior with Lightweight Solution enabled; may be Resharper...

Comment: Its quite possible that Resharper may have enabled it. You may like to read more about "LSL" option here at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/lightweight-solution-load-extension-impact

Comment: I think I am having a similar problem but I do not see that option. Is Lightweight Solution Load missing from VS2017 Community Edition?

Comment: @CraigSilver I resolved this by deleting the `csproj.user` file.

Answer (score 1):

For those who (like me) applied the [solution by @Pankaj Kapare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43913379/1805892) and **still** had the same problem:

1. Go to `Tools > Options > Projects and Solutions > General`

   - Notice the message `May be overridden for individual solutions`
2. Make sure `Always show solution` is ticked

   - click `OK`
3. Open Solution Explorer with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

   - click the solution
   - hit <kbd>F4</kbd> to open Properties
4. Make sure `Lightweight load` is set to `Disabled` or `Default`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by deleting the `csproj.user` file.